# R gamma function NaN warning

Tags: r

I'm trying to write an R program to optimize a function but I always get the gamma(k+1) NaNs produced warning. I don't know why because k+1 is supposed to be very small but not zero. Here is the code:

```
x<-rlnorm(100,0,1)
y<-x/(1+x)
bernsum<-array(1:100)
cvise1<-array(1:100)
cvise2=0
cvise<-0
bernsum_temp1=0
bernsum_temp2=0
cvise1_temp1=0
cvise1_temp2=0

func_bernise<-function(bigm)
{
  #Calculate the second part of CVISE
  for (i in 1:100)
{
    z<-y[-i]
    for (j in 1:99)
    {
      for (k in 0:bigm-1)
      {
         bernsum_temp1=bernsum_temp1+bigm*((sum(z[j]<=(k+1)/bigm)-sum(z[j]             
<=k/bigm))/100)*(gamma(bigm)/(gamma(k+1)*gamma(bigm-k+1)))
*(z[j]^k)*((1-z[j])^(bigm-k-1))/50

       }
      bernsum_temp2<-bernsum_temp2+bernsum_temp1
      bernsum_temp1=0
}
bernsum[i]=bernsum_temp2
bernsum_temp2=0
 }



cvise=sum(bernsum)#+sum(cvise1)
return(cvise)
}

bigmtrue=optimize(func_bernise,c(1,15))
```

Thanks in advance! You can see that k is from zero to bigm-1, with bigm being optimized from 1 to 15, which make k+1 from 1 to 15 too.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call your function, you need to pass it all of the variables used within it, or the variables need to be defined/initialized within the function if they are used and thrown away at the end of executing the function.

For example, you use the following inside your function without passing the variables to the function:

```
y
bernsum_temp1      #this is used in an assignment without being initialized
```

You can [check out this](http://www.statmethods.net/management/userfunctions.html) on writing functions.

EDIT1:
I forgot to mention that the reason NaNs are produced is because:

```
gamma(0) = NaN
```

So on your first pass through when  the following equals zero you will get the error

- bigm-k+1

Comment: Thanks Mr. Aaron Brown, I'll read more and make the modification accordingly. Yeah the error is from gamma(0).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the problem. optimize routine will set "bigm" to some non-integer values. So I must use 
    for (k in 0:round(bigm-1))
to solve the problem. I wish there were other optimization routine that focuses on integers.

Comment: your function returns `NaN` even for integer input `bigm`.

Comment: This is weird, as for me the program never gives warnings after I made the change. Anyway it seems to be working now. Thanks!